# BigQuery getQueryResults raises a 400 error for internal error

Tags: google-bigquery

We had a job fail last night around 3:02 AM US/Eastern with `getQueryResults()` raising a 400 HTTP error.
We use the Python Rest API (e.g. `jobs().getQueryResults()`).

According to [BigQuery Troubleshooting Errors](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors), BigQuery should be raising a 500 for these types of errors.

**ERROR:**

> The job encountered an internal error during execution and was unable
>   to complete successfully

Comment: 400 means "invalid input" -- perhaps the number was correct and you had an input error, even though the associated text was wrong.

Comment: True, this happened earlier due to the use of invalid time decorators although we log the SQL before submitting and ran it again this morning and it runs ok.